# jsf session or config problem

Tags: jsf-2

This is a sample from mkyong.com that I slightly modified. I added an inputtext and command
to send the next offset for paging in mysql. The first page autoloads with an offset of 0 as expected. If I type 5 in the inputtext, it actually works, and the next page displays the next 5 records. However, if I now enter 10, it stops working and page just keeps trying to load. I waited 5 minutes, nothing. Another retry, 0 first on load entered 15 just to test, it worked. But trying to make it work after first use of the commandButton, it just stalls.

In the url is displayed a current sessionid.  Is this a session problem, or a configuration problem?

I'm new to jsf, and am trying to learn how to properly send request through to make a page display something.  I got the inputText and commandButton idea direct from the javaeetutorial6 on oracles site, the guessnumber/duke example.

```
 package model;

    //import java.util.Date;

    public class Customer{

        public String petid;
        public String petname;
            public String tmpvar;
        private String offset;
        //public String address;
        //public Date created_date;
            //private String searchText;
            //public String getSearchText() { return searchText; }
            //public void setSearchText(String s) { searchText = s; }
        public String getpetid() {
            return petid;
        }
        public void setpetid(String petid) {
            this.petid = petid;
        }
        public String getpetname() {
            return petname;
        }
        public void setpetname(String petname) {
            this.petname = petname;
        }
        /*public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }
        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
        public Date getCreated_date() {
            return created_date;
        }
        public void setCreated_date(Date created_date) {
            this.created_date = created_date;
        }*/
            public String gettmpvar() {
            return tmpvar;
        }
        public void settmpvar(String tmpvar) {
            this.tmpvar = tmpvar;
        }



    }

package cust;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import model.Customer;

@ManagedBean(name="Customer")
//@SessionScoped

public class CustomerBean implements Serializable{
int userNumber;
String offset;
//String SearchText;
    //resource injection
    @Resource(name="jdbc/petback2")
    private DataSource ds;

    //if resource injection is not support, you still can get it manually.
    /*public CustomerBean(){
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/petback2");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
        }

    }*/

    //connect to DB and get customer list

        public String searchText;
    //private String offset;
        public String getSearchText() { return searchText; }
        public void setSearchText(String s) { searchText = s; }


        public List<Customer> getCustomerList() throws SQLException{
int rowsperpage = 5;
//String offset;
//HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
//offset = request.getParameter("offset");
//if (    offset == null ? "" == null : offset.equals(""))
//if (offset null ? "" == null : offset.equals("0")
//{
//getoffset();
//String voffset;
//voffset = offset;

if (offset == null)
    {
    offset = "0";
    }
System.out.println(offset);
//}
//int pageno = 0;
//int offset = 5;

//offset = "5";
//offset = CustomerBean.this.searchText;
//offset = getResponse();
        if(ds==null)
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");

        //get database connection
        Connection con = ds.getConnection();

        if(con==null)
            throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");

        PreparedStatement ps
            = con.prepareStatement(
               "select petid, petname from pets LIMIT "+ offset + ", " + rowsperpage);
                //"select petid, petname from pets LIMIT "+ offset + ", " + rowsperpage);
        //get customer data from database
        ResultSet result =  ps.executeQuery();

        List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
                //Customer cust2 = new Customer();
        while(result.next()){
            Customer cust2 = new Customer();

            cust2.setpetid(result.getString("petid"));
            cust2.setpetname(result.getString("petname"));
            //cust2.setAddress(result.getString("address"));
            //cust2.setCreated_date(result.getDate("created_date"));

            //store all data into a List
            list.add(cust2);
        }
                //List<Customer> list1 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
                //Customer cust3 = new Customer();
                Customer cust2 = new Customer();
                cust2.settmpvar("hello");
                list.add(cust2);
        return list;




    }

    public void setoffset(String user_number) {
        this.offset = user_number;
        System.out.println(offset);
    }

    public String getoffset() {
        return offset;
    }






}
```

newjsf.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">


    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css"  />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/myjq.js"></script>



    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>



        <h:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{Customer.customerList}" var="c" border="1"
                styleClass="order-table"
                headerClass="order-table-header"
                rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
            >

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    petid
                </f:facet>
                    #{c.petid}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    petname
                </f:facet>
                    #{c.petname}
            </h:column>



        </h:dataTable>
            <h:inputText
                    id="userNo"
                    value="#{Customer.offset}">

                </h:inputText>
<h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit"
                                 action="newjsf.xhtml"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <!--<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>-->
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/newjsf.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, changed over to ui:repeat, and used the below to send gets
instead of post:

```
<h:outputLink id="link1" value="newui.xhtml?voffset=#{Customer.offset - 5}">
    <h:outputText value="prev" />
</h:outputLink>

<h:outputLink id="link2" value="newui.xhtml?voffset=#{Customer.offset + 5}">
    <h:outputText value="next" />
</h:outputLink>
```

And in the bean:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            offset = req.getParameter("voffset");
            if (offset == null) {
                offset = "0";
            }
```

and,

```
public void setoffset(String voffset) {
        this.offset = voffset;
        //System.out.println(offset);
    }

    public String getoffset() {
        return offset;
    }
```

I don't know how, but the set/get works without a call to it, probably auto handled.
Anyway now paging works like a champ, and more control than a datatable.

Comment: Also notice none of that lazy loading stuff, pure limit clause through mysql, thus totally efficient, this can handle millions of records, because you only load however many you put in the rowsperpage var.  Seems that BalusC needs a many more lines of code